# html page does not display greek

Tags: html

I have the following html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

hello...

Салом...

γεια...
```

hello is being displayed, but *Салом* and *γεια*, which are in other languages, are not displayed.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what should I change to make messages in every language displayed successfully?

Comment: is that the real html, or did you omit `<body>` and the like? If that really is the html, then don't be surprised if it displays badly, since it'd be completely invalid.

Comment: no... there is <body> of course

Comment: The `meta` tag should be in the `head` tag, do you have a `head` tag? For the characters to show up correctly the file has to be saved as UTF-8, did you do that?

Comment: @user2491321 made some changes in answer try to replace bug in code

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- You have an HTTP header that says you are using a character encoding other than UTF-8 (which would override the meta) and you should fix that *or*
- You aren't saving the document as UTF-8 (in which case check the settings for your editor's SaveAs to make sure that you pick UTF-8 as the encoding) *or*
- Your are viewing the page on a system which doesn't have a font which supports those characters as a fallback for whatever font is being used by the page (in which case use a more common style of font)

Comment: Write what? Characters in UTF-8? See my answer. It's probably under SaveAs in your editor.

Comment: my code works fine on my localhost on my laptop... the problem is when I upload it to my hosting server

Comment: Then it is most likely the HTTP headers claiming the wrong encoding (see the first bullet point of the answer) and you need to fix the configuration of your hosting server.

Answer (score -1):

try this method

```
<div lang="fr-CA" xml:lang="fr-CA">
    Canadian French content...
    </div>
    <div lang="en-CA" xml:lang="en-CA">
    Canadian English content...
    </div>
    <div lang="nl-NL" xml:lang="nl-NL">
    Netherlands, Dutch content...
    </div>
```

use this method to change language inside div `<div lang="zh-CN">`

### method 2:

```
<html lang="en">
[...]
<body>
<h1>I am a heading <span lang="de-DE">Eine Überschrift</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### a bug in your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**replace**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**TO** content ends with semi-colon

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: The `lang` attribute doesn't influence the browser's rendering of characters.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />` is completely wrong. It isn't even well-formed now.

Answer (score -1):

if you want your document to register as greek you need to add `lang="el"` to your `html`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="el">
```

But understand simply adding a language to it does not translate or read your text as another language.  What you write is what it's going to show up as, it doesn't matter what language it is.

Your issue is most likely a formatting issue: At least if your document looks like the example you provided. Your `html` tag is not closed and your content is not inside `<body></body>` tags. It could be that you copied those words and pasted them in and they're not rendering as characters. It could be a few things. The text comes up fine in this fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/28zf25zg/)

Comment: It can't be the lang attribute because character encoding has nothing to do with language. It can't be the missing tags because the only error they would produce would be a yellow screen of death. It can't be a copy/paste error because it would have persisted when it was copy/pasted to stackoverflow.